# Responsive Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I recently added [responsive bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) to an application and things are working great. I've been able to make modifications to the layout based on screen resolutions like the following in my `application.css` file:

```
* // other stuff up here...//
*
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
*= require_tree .
*/

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #winner_table { max-width: 30%; }
}
```

Now, I'm wondering if it's possible to make modifications like these to my javascript based on screen resolution? Specifically, I want a popover on an element to float right by default, but float up when using a phone. What are my options to do something like this? I may be incorrect assuming Responsive Bootstrap can solve the problem, but I feel like it is a solvable problem somehow.

Comment: there's not a real implementation for that but you can get the browser width in jQuery with `$(window).width()` and adjust your popover options accordingly

Comment: Ok cool. And that method will return what exactly? The number of pixels?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://viget.com/inspire/managing-javascript-on-responsive-websites). it goes over jsRespond, which you might find helpful

Comment: or read http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/responsive-banner-ads-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use matchmedia.js to call certain jQuery elements - https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/